# Jsp cannot parse <br>

Tags: java, jsp

I have some thing like `みなさん、こんにちは**<br>**みなさん、こんにちは`  in my db2 database. When I request this from jsp page, ideally because of `<br>` it should display like
`みなさん、こんにちは`
`みなさん、こんにちは` but `<br> tag` is not parsing in jsp page. It is displaying as
`みなさん、こんにちは**<br>** みなさん、こんにちは`
How to solve this issue.

Comment: How are you printing the result from DB into the JSP? The <br> is probably escaped.

Comment: I am populating the string value to a bean and using use bean I am displaying. is this because of format (utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `<br>` with a trailing front slash? Like this:

```
This is something I need to print.<br/>
Oh a new line! That is nice!
```